Why doesn't `str.erase(0, 0)` erase the first character of a string?
According to cplusplus,

first, last
Iterators specifying a range within the string] to be removed: [first,last). i.e., the range includes all the characters between first and last, including the character pointed by first but  not the one pointed by last.

In which first, last are the parameters for the string::erase function. So str.erase(0, 0) should work. However, it doesn't erase any character, and the string is left as normal. Which is strange, as the first character of a string is denoted by 0.
However, when trying str.erase(0, 1), the first character of the string is erased, which makes sense, as https://cplusplus.com words it as 'Includes all the characters between first and last, including the character pointed by first but not the one pointed by last.'
I first thought of it being that not having the last character removed had priority over removing the first character, however this can't be right, as running str.erase(1, 1) erases the second character of the string.
Why is this? Is this just an issue in the language itself?

Unrelated:I would recommend cppreference over cplusplus.

The overload you're looking at is for using iterators. If you pass integer values, you use the one where you specify a position and the length. And since you specify a length of zero, nothing is erased.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase str.erase(0.0) will trigger version (1) of erase which specifies index and count. As count = 0 you don't erase anything.

Also, version (3) of the erase - which requires one to put iterators rather than numbers - erases elements in [first, last), so if first == last then it erases nothing.

And regarding iterators, remember that the end is the last plus one. So even if it worked as you expected it would require erase(0, 1).

If you were to call the iterator overload with an empty range, e.g. str.erase(str.begin() + 1, str.begin() + 1), you would see nothing removed too.

@user12002570 Any particular reason why? Or just personal preference?

@somebodywhodoesntknowmuch It is more well-maintained and so up to date than cplusplus. Also more well written.

@somebodywhodoesntknowmuch It's also harder to read than cplusplus but it is worth the effort to get used to its style. It's a superb site, authoritative, comprehensive, etc. Apart from being a great reference you can actually learn a lot of C++ from it.

str.erase(0,0) uses the version that takes an index and a count. From std::string::erase:

basic_string& erase( size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos );     (1) (constexpr since C++20)


Removes std::min(count, size() - index) characters starting at index.


As you can see, the behavior is to remove std::min(count, size() - index) characters starting from first passed argument index.
In your case, count is 0, so you are removing 0 characters.

The integer 0 is not an iterator. Therefore, str.erase(0,0) calls the (index, count) overload.
